# Special char plugin in CQ's rich text editor

Tags: aem, rich-text-editor

I have modified the CQ’s rich text editor with the special char plugins. But the issue is, this includes the html source editing plugin also. I don’t want to include that in my rich text editor. Is there any way that I can include special chars but not html source editing. Basically i don’t want the html editing option in RTE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `specialchars` feature is made available through the `misctools` plugin which also contains the `sourceedit` feature.

In order to activate specific features of the plugin, the `features` property has to be a `String[]` with values of the specific feature you require as shown below.

```
"rtePlugins": {
    "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured",
    "misctools": {
        "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured",
        "features": ["sourceedit"]
    }
}
```

In case you the `features` property is of type `String` and value is `*`, then it would include all the features of the plugin. Probably that is why you are getting `sourceedit` along with `specialchars`.

[Configuring the Rich Text Editor](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/administering/configuring_rich_text_editor.html) might help you understand more on using the rich text editor in AEM. Also refer the [API documentation for the MiscToolsPlugin](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.rte.plugins.MiscToolsPlugin).